# I cannot insert data into Table while the DB table is empty

Tags: mysql, database, spring-mvc, mysql-error-1064

I have written save method in my controller class using Spring MVC , such that is following

```
// To save record  
@RequestMapping(value = "/save", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String saveRole(@Valid UserRoleResource roleDTO, ModelMap modelMap) {
    UserRole roleCreated = userRoleService.create(mapper.toUserRole(roleDTO));
    modelMap.addAttribute("user_role", roleCreated);
    modelMap.addAttribute("RoleId", roleCreated.getRoleId());
    return "UserManagement/role_details";
}
```

These are working successfully When I call this method, only if there are no any data in DB table (UserROle), then the data are not entered properly into DB.I want to insert my data into fresh or empty table.
I checked that, the given data inserts into the table entirely if the table contains minimum one or more rows initially.How to fix it?plz anybody help

Comment: What do you see in your logs when the exception occurs?

Comment: Thank you ! I have solved this problem